# Javascript "document.write" confusion

Tags: javascript, dom, document.write

I'm new to JavaScript and may have asked a dumb question.. But the result returned from below code made me so confused. I'm not sure why only the first sentence show the value of i and it was in the last number of 3.

I'm also confused when the code `document.write('<h1>' + i + msg + '<h1>')` being executed, why it didn't just write the aggregated value of the variable 'msg'? The value of msg didn't get wiped out and it should contain both the 1st and 2nd value passed into it isn't it? This looks a bit confusing to me as I came with some python knowledge and it didn't work in the same way.

```js
var scores = [24, 32, 47];
var scores = [24, 32, 47];
var scores = [24, 32, 47];

var arrayLength = scores.length;
var roundNumber = 0;

var msg = '';
var i;


for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  roundNumber = i + 1;
  msg += ' Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';
  msg += scores[i] + '<br>';
}

document.write('<h1>' + i + msg + '<h1>')
```

Result returned from the html:

```
3 Round 1: 24 
Round 2: 32 
Round 3: 47
```

My expected result:

```
0 Round 1: 24
1 Round 2: 32
2 Round 3: 47
```

Comment: Because by the time you get to `document.write('<h1>' + i + msg + '<h1>')`, `i` is 3. If you want the loop index in front of the round, add it to `msg += ' Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';`. E.g. `msg += i + '  Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';`

Comment: <code>
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  roundNumber = i + 1;
  msg = ' Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';
  msg += scores[i] + '<br>';
  document.write('<h1>' + i + msg + '<h1>')
}
</code>

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. But in thise case, why the variable 'msg' not behaved like the 'i', which should only display the last iterated value?

e.g Round 3: 47 ?

Comment: `why the variable 'msg' not behaved like the 'i'`...because you keep on adding to its content within the loop, whereas the value of `i` gets overwritten each time you loop. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69573707/5947043) below for further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` runs after the end of the loop.

It *does* output all the aggregated content of `msg`. That isn't the issue.

The bit that's going wrong is the use of `i` - you only use it once in the output, after the loop ends. Therefore what you see will only have the final value it had when the loop ended, hence it shows `3`, and does so once only.

Unlike `msg` which you are adding to each time the loop runs (because `+=` appends new content to the existing variable), the value of `i` is overwritten with a new value each time the loop runs (that's what the `i++` in the `for` syntax does).

To make it do what you want you simply need to incorporate the `i` value into `msg` as you go along instead.

```js
var scores = [24, 32, 47];
var msg = '';

for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  msg += i + ' Round ' + (i+1) + ': ' + scores[i] + '<br>';
}

document.write('<h1>' + msg + '<h1>')
```

P.S. I also simplified the code slightly - it's unclear why you declared the same `scores` array 3 times with the same value, and `arrayLength` and `roundNumber` don't need to exist as separate variables, and certainly not ones which have scope outside the loop. `i` also doesn't need scope outside the loop anymore.

Comment: Thanks ADyson. That's exactly the point where I get lost.. why when i use 'msg' it instead will print 3 seperated sentence instead of printing one aggregated sentence e.g  "Round  1: 24 Round 2:32 Round 3: 47" or maybe just print once of its final value e.g Round 3: 47? Because from my understanding the 'msg' added a new value on top of it existing value as it didn't get reset each time? ( that's what I expected it should behave like in python)

Comment: `it instead will print 3 seperated sentence` ...if by "separated" you mean "on separate lines", that's because you used `<br>` in the message text, which is HTML's tag indicating that a new line should be started. That's nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: `my understanding the 'msg' added a new value on top of it existing value as it didn't get reset each time`...that's correct, and that is exactly what is happening. Like I said in the answer, your use of `msg` is not the problem, it's your use of `i` which caused the incorrect output.

Comment: ahhh i got it.. i neglected there's a <br> tag... much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the i to the message in the loop instead of after, like:

```js
var scores = [24, 32, 47];
var arrayLength = scores.length;
var roundNumber = 0;
var msg = '';
var i;

for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  roundNumber = i + 1;
  msg += i +' Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';
  msg += scores[i] + '<br>';
}

document.write('<h1>' + msg + '<h1>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You output `i` only once. That is why you see only the last value.

You need to add it to `msg` inside the loop.

```js
var scores = [24, 32, 47];
var scores = [24, 32, 47];
var scores = [24, 32, 47];

var arrayLength = scores.length;
var roundNumber = 0;

var msg = '';
var i;


for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  roundNumber = i + 1;
  msg += i + ' Round ' + roundNumber + ': ';
  msg += scores[i] + '<br>';
}

document.write('<h1>' +  msg + '<h1>')
```